# Why did I lose stats when rubbing a card in Monster Monpiece?

Tags: monster-monpiece

I just unlocked the "rubbing" feature which I thought was supposed to strengthen cards. However, I just LOST 1 attack and 2 HP off a card (Snow Owl) after rubbing it. It still has  it's original high mana cost, so the cards are basically useless now. Elevating it to level 3 did not fix (or further harm) the stats, and I don't have enough power to raise it to level 4 yet.

If it matters, I rubbed the whole stack of cards at once. I'm not especially good at the rubbing game yet but I did complete it and had some time left. Why would I lose stats when "upgrading" a card? Is it random, or do certain cards just always get decreases in stats or what's going on here? A couple other cards DID increase in stats.

Answer (score 2):

The stats didn't get *universally* worse on Snow Owl: when upgraded Snow Owl loses some HP and Attack, but gains a Skill that prevents it from moving, and it's range increases from 2 to 3. Worth noting that range beyond 2 is considered a very valuable stat as clearly shown by the mana cost of several cards.

Some cards apparently also reduce in stats AND mana cost, but generally speaking not all cards will get a straight upgrade, but they may instead get increased versatility or gain some niche use due to potentials or skills.

In Snow Owl's case it makes it more of a stationary guard you can use to block a whole lane (with sufficient buffs, since it's dismal attack will otherwise limit you). Fia starts off as a more capable blocker, but 3 Snow Owls in the back column with 3+ Large Bonuses (HP/ATK up) will make attacking your HQ extremely difficult. You could also use buffers behind the Snow owls but this will make attacking very difficult as you've locked 2 of 3 columns.

Bonuses by level are set by card and are always the same, though I don't know what all of them do, you'd need a big ol' spreadsheet for that due to the number of cards and all the -1, +1 etc cards there are in the game.